# How to open an activity in half of the screen in android?

Tags: android-activity

I want to open an activity in half of the screen, so that half of the background activity is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach-1** If you want to show one activity on the top of another activity, then make  the top activity as transparent or translucent theme in its layout, It will give you the similar look and feel. But the background elements will not clickable.

**Approach-2** You can use multiple fragments to get similar look, benefit is that background elements are also click-able

Comment: for approach 2, Fragment can be also used before Honeycomb when using support-v4 package from google.